# Multi Threading gives some weird results

Tags: c++, multithreading

I just used Multi threading. It works but it gives some weird results and every time i run the program the results are different.Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong

Now in my output i'm supposed to have 2 blocks which continuously move up and down but in actual output some other blocks appear out of nowhere you can see my output in the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SwXHsJjp4Os)

(i.e i excluded the global char array from the main code i am adding  another code section so you can  run my code and help me )

**Main Code**

```
#include<iostream>      //libraries
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<thread>

using namespace std;

void print();
void gotoxy(int,int);
int race();
void block1();
void block2();

COORD coord={0,0};//global variable
    char road[22][80]={//haven't mentioned the array  }; //global char array 

void main()
{
    race(); 
}

int race()
{
        char swap;

    //printing the array once
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0 ; i<22 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<80 ; j++)
        {
            cout<<road[i][j];
        }
    }

    thread t1 (block2);
    thread t2 (block1);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

  getch();
  return 0;
}

void block1()           //definition of block1
{
    char swap;
    int i=1 , j=4;
    while(!kbhit())
    {
        while(road[i+1][j]!='\xdb')
        {
            swap=road[i][j];
            road[i][j]=road[i+1][j];
            road[i+1][j]=swap;
            gotoxy(4,i+1);
            cout<<road[i][j];
            gotoxy(4,i+2);
            cout<<road[i+1][j];
            Sleep(200);
            i++;
        }

        if(road[i+1][j]=='\xdb')

        while(road[i-1][j]!='\xdb')
            {
            swap=road[i][j];
            road[i][j]=road[i-1][j];
            road[i-1][j]=swap;
            gotoxy(4,i);
            cout<<road[i-1][j];
            gotoxy(4,i+1);
            cout<<road[i][j];
            Sleep(500);
            i--;
            }

     }
}

void block2()           //definition of function block2
{
    char swap;
    int i=1 , j=7;
    while(!kbhit())
    {
        while(road[i+1][j]!='\xdb')
        {
            swap=road[i][j];
            road[i][j]=road[i+1][j];
            road[i+1][j]=swap;
            gotoxy(7,i+1);
            cout<<road[i][j];
            gotoxy(7,i+2);
            cout<<road[i+1][j];
            Sleep(50);
            i++;
        }

        if(road[i+1][j]=='\xdb')

        while(road[i-1][j]!='\xdb')
            {
            swap=road[i][j];
            road[i][j]=road[i-1][j];
            road[i-1][j]=swap;
            gotoxy(7,i);
            cout<<road[i-1][j];
            gotoxy(7,i+1);
            cout<<road[i][j];
            Sleep(50);
            i--;
            }

    }
}
```

**Global Char Array**

```
char road[22][80]={        //global char array 
'\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','\xdb','.','.','\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb',1,'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','\xdb',
'\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb','\xdb',


                        };
```

Comment: I can't spot any race protection mechanisms, could it be you're running into race conditions?

Comment: the name maybe misleading it's not a race

Comment: Well, both threads operate on the same array at the same time, without any exclusive access protection. If that's not a race condition, I don't know what else should be.

Comment: yeah they are working on the same array but different columns 
the blocks act as barriers which the player has to avoid

Comment: What makes you so sure, that access address calculation and changing the value are done in a single non interruptible machine instruction?

Comment: How could you possibly have missed the section on _mutual exclusion_ when learning about threads? Go read on what a `mutex` is, and how to use them. Very crucial.

Comment: Ty all, like i said i just used multi threading so i don't know much about it.

Comment: @RiccardoMutschlechner I used mutex and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a race condition when you are outputting to the screen. For example, if thread one is running

```
        gotoxy(4,i+1);
        cout<<road[i][j];
```

and execution switches to thread 2 after the `gotoxy(4,i+1);`. Thread 2 then does its own

```
        gotoxy(7,i+1);
        cout<<road[i][j];
```

The location of the output cursor will now be (8, i+1). Then when thread 1 gets to run again, it will use `cout<<road[i][j];` which will output to the current cursor, which is in the incorrect place.

To fix this, you would have to use race protection mechanisms, as πάντα ῥεῖ said. Something like a mutex would work.

Comment: They execute separately, but they both work on the same process and share memory etc. While your memory accesses aren't affected as you are looking at separate parts of the array, there is only one output console and one cursor position. The same thing would occur for anything else you call that uses shared resources.

Answer (score 0):

You have race conditions because `road` is read from and written to in multiple threads. You need to protect *every* access to the array in boths threads. Only the “printing the array once” loop is fine because it runs before the other threads are spawned.

```
// global scope
std::mutex road_mx;

// ...

void block1() {
    while //... {
        // ...

        while(road[i+1][j]!='\xdb') {  // <-- problem, see below
            {  // <-- scope for the lock guard
                std::lock_guard<std::muxtex> lock(road_mx);
                // do stuff with road
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
}

// ...
```

The access to `road` in the *while* condition is a problem. You probably don’t want to put a *lock_guard* around the whole *while* loop because the less time spent under the lock the less contention between the threads and the faster your program runs.

The easiest solution is to introduce local variables where you copy values from the array to. Those are local – i.e. exclusive – to the current thread and so don’t need guarding.